# Display RoR View in Fancy box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, fancybox

Is it possible to have method on controller that renders a view that will be in the fancy box?

Here is my code:

```
<a id="someId" href="#htmlForFancyBox">Open Fancy Box</a>

    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="htmlForFancyBox">
                 <!-- html that will be rendered in fancy box -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Desired code:

```
 # Method on controller that will render view 
  def view_for_fancy_box    

  end
```

I am aware that I need to create view_for_fancy_box.html.erb file that will have all html that is in the display: none div above.

How to achieve view rendering in fancy box?

Thanks

Comment: I guess yes ... what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to put all html that shuld go to view onto the same page where the link is. Then link it to link via id in href.

Comment: Show your code maybe we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that structure, just use this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#someId").fancybox({
  // API options here
 });//fancybox
}); // ready
</script>
```

Don't forget to load the proper fancybox js and css files.

Also make sure you add the right API options for the version you are using

If using v1.3.4 check http://fancybox.net/api.

For v2.x check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Which api is for loading view into fancy box content?

Comment: first just try it without any (click on the link to `#htmlForFancyBox`)